# Div wiggles when overlay appears

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a div (the blue card with css3 logo) that wiggles when I hover the I Icon, you can view the problem here :

http://lab.stephenbe.ca/portfolio/portfoliov3/

I have no idea why this is happening, I tried recreating the problem in codepen :

http://codepen.io/stephenbe/pen/FckrH

And the bug does not appear at all. I noticed that if your screen is small, the bug does not appear. The screen has to be around 1600 in size.

The bug appears in the latest version of chrome

Thank you

Edit : here is a screencast of it http://screenr.com/EQkH

The css the moves the div is as follows:

```
.portfolio .card.active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  visibility: visible;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: nothing wiggles under ie and last chrome

Comment: http://screenr.com/EQkH pay attention to the blue card...it moves a little to the left when I hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) to the body.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a Webkit/Blink bug because of the transition applied to the image blur filter. During the transition, it appears the position of the card on top of the image is not calculated correctly, and therefore shifts slightly. The combination of that with your very precise percentage margins and widths are causing what is likely rounding differences/errors in the browser rendering.

Thus, there are three options you have. You can not transition to the blur, just blur. Or, make your measurements for width and margin on the cards less precise (i.e. round your percentages a bit more generously). Then there is always the option to just ignore it and wait for Chrome to fix the issue.

If you can isolate the case, I'd highly recommend [filing a bug against Chrome](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines).

Comment: Because the image isn't found, so the transition doesn't happen. There also appears to be some other issues showing up (at least on my Chrome instance) around flashing content, which may have to do with switching to using accelerated rendering during the transition in an `<iframe>`

Comment: I added the photo and its still not doing the bug http://codepen.io/stephenbe/pen/FckrH  

full version http://codepen.io/stephenbe/full/FckrH

Comment: On my version of Chrome, the bug reproduces using the full version in your comment.

Comment: Alright before I give you the bounty, how can I actually believe that this is an actual chrome bug and not something I forgot, a style that I could add to fix it...Is it something you saw happen before?

Comment: @Stephen Well, first, you won't be able to award the bounty until 24 hours after you set it. Second, you are more than able to wait for another answer. And third, given that you are working with highly experimental features, I'd say I can't really prove it, but by isolating and filing a Chrome bug, they would be able to tell you. That all said, you *might* be able to work around the issue by forcing GPU accelerated rendering on those elements all the time (and there are many tricks to do this).